# In VS Code, how can I make a custom "go to definition" functionality for a non-supported language?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm working with a propietary programming language and I would like to implement a "go to definition" functionality. I have to make one of my own because as I said the language is propietary and it is not supported by any plugin. What is the best way to achieve this? Is there something like a general purpose plugin where you can add rules to fetch function definitions? Do I have to make my own plugin?

Comment: Assume that language has a compiler, and you can use the same code base to write a language server, and then a VSCode extension for that language.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an extension which supports your proprietary language. This is a pretty big task and cannot be answered in a single SO question. So start getting familiar how to write such an extension and which providers you have to create to support the features you want.